# Set jQuery dialog button state from javascript function

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-dialog

Is it possible to set a jQuery ui dialog button state to enable in a standard javascript, not jQuery function.

I have a dialog button with the id btnSaveRecord that needs to be enabled after meeting certain conditions once processed through some javascript functions that I would rather not rewrite if possible.

I have tried:

```
document.getElementById("btnSaveRecord").removeAttribute("disabled");
document.getElementById("btnSaveRecord").disabled = false;
```

and alerts show the code either side fires but neither work. I am guessing it is because these are in a jQuery ui dialog.

Comment: Can you share more of your code?  Why don't you want to use the proper jQuery syntax for enabling the button?  It sounds like you're needing to rewrite your code anyway.

Comment: What's a dialog button? Are you referring to a button you have that opens a dialog?

Comment: @j08691 Look at the name of the button in his code -- it's a control within the dialog.

Comment: What's wrong with using jquery if you are already using jquery-ui anyway?

Comment: something else is going on here. That javascript is fine and should work. You either have a bad selector somewhere or you're not triggering it right or who knows. More code is needed to debug. Try making a fiddle with your problem.

Comment: Why if you have a jQuery UI dialog you don't want to use jQuery? Can you provide more context or a demo on jsfiddle?

Comment: Sorry im an idiot, the button was being enabled its just that the dialog didnt refresh to show it was enabled. I think i just need to remove the classes that show it as diabled.